# Why is this list printing out ONLY the last character?

Tags: c#

so ive been working on this program that analyzes a certain input file, almost everything is outputting correctly EXCEPT the keywords List.

heres the code snippet regarding the keyword list and related functions:

```
public class Token //Token structure to be added for each Token in the tokenTable
{
    public string value;
    public string type;
}

internal static class Define_input_output
{
    public const string inFile = "input.txt"; //set file to read
    public const string outFile = "output.txt"; //set file to write to
}

public static void placeKeywords_in_keywordsTable(List<string> keywords, List<Token> keywordTable)
{
    Token newToken = new Token();

    for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Count; i++) //loop through each keyword
    {
        newToken.value = keywords[i]; //add keyword[i] to newToken's value
        newToken.type = "KW"; //assign "kw" to newToken's type
        keywordTable.Add(newToken); //push newToken to keywordTable
    }
}

public static void print_Tables_to_outputFile(StreamWriter output, List<Token> keywordTable)
{
    output.Write("\r\n"); 
    output.Write("-".PadRight(21, '-'));
    output.Write("\r\n"); 
    output.Write(' ');
    output.Write("Keyword ".PadRight(11));
    output.Write("|".PadRight(2));
    output.Write("Index");
    output.Write("\r\n");
    output.Write("-".PadRight(21, '-'));
    output.Write("\r\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < keywordTable.Count; i++) //loop through each element in keywordTable
    {
        output.Write(' ');
        output.Write((keywordTable[i].value).PadRight(10));
        output.Write(" |".PadRight(7));
        output.Write(i);
        output.Write("\r\n");
    }
}

static int Main()
{
    StreamReader input = new StreamReader(Define_input_output.inFile);//input file
    StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(Define_input_output.outFile);//output file

    List<string> keywords = new List<string>() { "else", "if", "int", "return", "void", "while", "+", "-", "*", "/", "<", "<=", ">", ">=", "==", "!=", "=", ";", ",", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "/*", "*/" };
    List<Token> keywordTable = new List<Token>();

    placeKeywords_in_keywordsTable(keywords, keywordTable); //place all the keywords into keywordTable

    while (!input.EndOfStream) //read each line until end of file
    {
        read_inputFile(input, output, keywordTable);
    }

    print_Tables_to_outputFile(output, keywordTable); 

    input.Close(); //close input file
    output.Close(); //close output file

    return 0;
}
```

The issue im having is only this "*/" character is being printed out to the keyword table. its indexed 26 times (which is right amount of indexing since thats how many chars are in the list).
I tested this by having remove the last two characters from the list, and the "}" character started printing 26 times instead.

I have no idea whats missing as I have carefully looked at the code multiple times and I just cant spot what the issue is. 
Any help is appreciated. thanks!

[image: keywordTable output image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your `placeKeywords_in_keywordsTable` method. You initialize the `Token` only once and then in each iteration of the loop you update it. So basically you are left with only the last `keyword`

Change to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Count; i++) //loop through each keyword
{
    Token newToken = new Token();
    newToken.value = keywords[i]; //add keyword[i] to newToken's value
    newToken.type = "KW"; //assign "kw" to newToken's type
    keywordTable.Add(newToken); //push newToken to keywordTable
}
```

A nicer way is to use this form of initializing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < keywords.Count; i++) //loop through each keyword
{
    Token newToken = new Token
    {
        value = keywords[i],
        type = "KW"
    };
    keywordTable.Add(newToken); //push newToken to keywordTable
}
```

even better will be to use a `foreach` loop instead of a `for`:

```
foreach(var i in keywords)
{
    Token newToken = new Token
    {
        value = i,
        type = "KW"
    };
    keywordTable.Add(newToken);
}
```

And if you want to do it using linq:

```
keywordTable = keywords.Select(item => new Token { value = item, type = "KW" }).ToList();
```

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you